# LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_hereMapController@17401934' has not been initialized.)

Tags: flutter, dart, here-api

I have an app built off the HERE SDK.

There is a class within the SDK called HereMapController that allows edits to the map etc.

I am trying to implement it within my main.dart to allow me to add map markers within main.dart as well as my other files (That work fine). I've tried most ways to get it working but cannot within main.dart

Here is the top of my main.dart, where I introduce it

```
void main() {  
  SdkContext.init(IsolateOrigin.main);
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'DMSans'),
    home: MyApp(), 
   ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
} 

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late HereMapController? _hereMapController;
...
```

It suggested adding late, which I think means I then have to initialise it elsewhere but I am not sure how to go about that.

It doesn't always link to the class when I hover over it, sometimes just a `null` type.

Further down I then call it with

```
    _hereMapController?.mapScene.addMapMarker(mapMarker);
```

It always fails on the `null check` on `_hereMapController?.mapScene...`

The SDK - https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-explore/4.4.0.2/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html

An example of the SDK in main.dart - https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/carto_poi_picking_app/lib/main.dart

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: use like this: ```HereMapController? _hereMapController;``` or ```late HereMapController _hereMapController;```

Comment: I have tried that already and throws error ```_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)``` on the implementation at ``` _hereMapController?.mapScene.addMapMarker```

Comment: Remove 'late' keyword and use like this:

 HereMapController? _hereMapController;

Comment: I have edited my comment. Please try again. The cast error is showing maybe because you haven't initilased that controller. Do it in the ```initState``` or maybe after you fetch some data from APIs.

Comment: Still says ```_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)``` on both suggestions. When I hover over ```HereMapController? _hereMapController;``` it says ```null```, wheras in my other file it shows the Class and its SDK credentials

Answer (score 1):

Lateinitalization error will occur if the variable is created but not initialized.

In the example you have referred you have created a variable:

```
 late HereMapController? _hereMapController;
```

But it's not been initialized:

As referring to the link you have shared the "`_hereMapController`" is created and it has been initialized in the `_onMapCreated()` method

[image]